# QString::fromWCharArray gives strange charracters

Tags: c++, qt

I have a string named `aDrive = "H:/"`

i want to convert this string into WCHAR so used like below

```
WCHAR Drive[4];

aDrive.toWCharArray ( Drive ) ;
```

when i printed it `qDebug ()<<QString::fromWCharArray ( Drive );`

it displays like `"H:/???"`

why i get the starnge charracters at the end..

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QString::toWCharArray()` does not zero-terminate the array. Without an explicit array length with `QString::fromWCharArray()`, it will read wchars until a zero wchar is read. In this case, you'll have to add the zero wchar yourself at the end, or use explicit length parameter with `QString::fromWCharArray()`.

As always, the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html) is your friend.

Comment: Even when I zero-terminated or used the explicit length parameter, I experienced strange behavior. So, for anyone having the same issue, try this: Use `std::wstring` as "storage" and call `c_str()` if you need the `const wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my guess.

According to the toWCharArray [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstring.html#toWCharArray): **This function does not append a null character to the array.** The returned string was not properly terminated with null. When you printed it, the part of memory after the memory allocated for the Drive array was also printed until a null byte is reached.